# How do I detect when I've reached the end of an array in a react functional component?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, indexing, use-state, react-functional-component

I have a simple component that contains an array of animal names (cow, horse, chicken) and a button that when clicked, increments the index of the array to display the name of the next animal. I want to know once I've reached the end of the array so that I can redirect the user.  How can I achieve this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Test() {

    const [array, setArray] = useState(['cow', 'horse', 'chicken'])
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

    const handleClick = () => {
        setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Next animal</button>
            <h2>{array[index]}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I had tried to add a conditional statement to the callback function along the following lines, but it did not work:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    if(index < array.length){
        setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1)
    } else {
        alert("We've reached the end of the array, redirect user!")
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you wanting to navigate the user when the next click would index out of the array? Or when they reach the last element?

Comment: Yes, I want to navigate the user when the next click would index out of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're off by 1. The last index will be `array.length - 1`, so compare against that:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [array, setArray] = React.useState(['cow', 'horse', 'chicken'])
    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)

    const handleClick = () => {
        if(index === array.length - 1){
            alert("We've reached the end of the array, redirect user!")
        } else {
            setIndex(index + 1);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Next animal</button>
            <h2>{array[index]}</h2>
        </div>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: See live snippet, it looks to work as desired?

Comment: "the index value when called inside the callback is always the value set originally"
Why would you expect that? 
This behavior exists only if you use `useCallback`, but even, you'll need to have your `index` in your dependency array, so it'll work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you will hit the `handleClick` function the `index` state will be updated by one. According to the condition applied inside the `handleClick` function whenever the `index` state number reaches equal reaches above the numbers of elements present inside an array it will show an alert.

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setindex(index + 1)
    if (index >= array.length - 1 ) {
        alert("We've reached the end of the array, redirect user!")
    }
}
```